# dev_appserver.py no such file or directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to enable sending email in development. So I need to run server.
I am in a directory called 'trade' where my application is located.(See pwd and ls)

```
Kenzos-MacBook-Pro:trade kenzotakahashi$ pwd
/Users/kenzotakahashi/desktop/main/WebDevelopment/project/trade
Kenzos-MacBook-Pro:trade kenzotakahashi$ ls
app.yaml    main.pyc    model.pyc   util.py
main.py     model.py    templates   util.pyc
```

But I got this error.

```
Kenzos-MacBook-Pro:trade kenzotakahashi$ dev_appserver.py trade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 184, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 180, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Users/kenzotakahashi/Desktop/main/WebDevelopment/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 727, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/kenzotakahashi/Desktop/main/WebDevelopment/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 720, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/kenzotakahashi/Desktop/main/WebDevelopment/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 554, in start
    options.yaml_files)
  File "/Users/kenzotakahashi/Desktop/main/WebDevelopment/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 556, in __init__
    module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(yaml_path)
  File "/Users/kenzotakahashi/Desktop/main/WebDevelopment/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 82, in __init__
    self._yaml_path)
  File "/Users/kenzotakahashi/Desktop/main/WebDevelopment/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 271, in _parse_configuration
    with open(configuration_path) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trade'
Kenzos-MacBook-Pro:trade kenzotakahashi$
```

Here is my app.yaml

```
application: trade
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"
```

I know there is no file called 'trade' but google document says "dev_appserver.py myapp"
So I thought 'trade' would be myapp name. I also tried dev_appserver.py with 'main.py', 'main.app', 'main' but none of them worked.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the path when you run `dev_appserver.py`.  If you are running the app server from inside of the `trade` directory, you could run either

```
dev_appserver.py .
```

or

```
dev_appserver.py ../trade
```

Another way to run it is to `cd ..` so you're in the directory that contains `trade` and then run

```
dev_appserver.py trade
```

Comment: I have tried that one as well. Then I got this error.  `google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8080`

Comment: Bind error is unrelated.  You have some other process listening on port 8080.  Pick a different port or shut the service down.

Comment: Thanks! That problem was that I already ran the server using Launcher.